# Dates in One Reports are being shown in Hijri(Arabic system for Calender) for only one pc

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdlc, gregorian-calendar

Using rdlc, SQL Server and C#, the dates in only one report being shown in Hijri (other reports are being shown in Gregorian calendar), for only on PC in the network while for other PCs all reports are shown in Gregorian calendar,

I have tried to uninstall the software and install it again, removed registry values,

I can't figure out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess...

- That report has the "Language" property set to "User.Language"
- The browser/user on that PC is set to Arabic

If the report property is left to default, it uses the SSRS server settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below link will help u :-

[Multi-Lingual or Global Deployments for SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)